How do I set window height to 35px for an installed PWA?
For an installed PWA, I am unable to set the height of the window (using window.resizeTo) to 35px.
It would appear the minimum height is 108px. The titlebar is 35px so 108px seems strange to me. I am using Chrome on Windows 10.
I have no content and have tried: html, body { height: 0; min-height: 0 }.
Any ideas on how to resize the window to the height of the titlebar so just the titlebar is visible?
EDIT: You can manually resize the window such that only the titlebar is visible.

Chrome enforces a minimum height for windows, 108px. That's probably why you can't achieve 35px height

I'm able to manually resize this window to smaller than this?

I think not. Maybe with some workaround but that is not by the book
